# How do I expand $\frac{1}{\sqrt{ (\boldsymbol{r-r'})^2+a} }$ in legendre polynomials (spherical harmonics)?

Tags: real-analysis, generating-functions, legendre-polynomials, greens-function

Using the generating function for the legendre polynomial: $$ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} P_{n}(x) t^{n}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-2 x t+t^{2}}} $$ It's possible to expand the coulomb potential in a basis of legendre polynomials (or even spherical harmonic ) like this: $$ \begin{aligned} &\frac{1}{\left.\mid \vec{r}-\vec{r}^{\prime}\right]}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{r^{2}+r^{\prime 2}-2 r r^{\prime}\left(\hat{r} \cdot \hat{r}^{\prime}\right)}}= \sum_{\ell=0}^{\infty} \frac{r_{<}^{\ell}}{r_{>}^{\ell+1}} P\left(\hat{r} \cdot \hat{r}^{\prime}\right) \\ &=\sum_{\ell=0}^{\infty} \frac{4 \pi}{2 \ell+1} \frac{r_{<}^{\ell}}{r_{>}^{\ell+1}} \sum_{m=-\ell}^{\ell} Y_{\ell m}^{\star}\left(\vartheta^{\prime}, \varphi^{\prime}\right) Y_{\ell m}(\vartheta, \varphi) \end{aligned} $$ Where $r_{<}$ and $r_{>}$ represent the smaller and larger of $r$ and $r^{\prime}$.

But I need to expand
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{ (\boldsymbol{r-r'})^2+a} }=\frac{1}{\sqrt{r^{2}+r^{\prime 2}-2 r r^{\prime}\left(\hat{r} \cdot \hat{r}^{\prime}\right)+a}}$$
In a similar way. However, I can't seem to pull out a factor of $r$ or $r'$ to get the generating function as you can above, because of the addition of $a$.
So how do I expand this expression in legendre polynomials?

Comment: When you say "in a similar way", do you mean a decoupling $\sum_\ell F_\ell(r)G_\ell(r')P_\ell(\hat{\mathbf{r}}\cdot\hat{\mathbf{r}}')$ of the $\mathbf{r}$ and $\mathbf{r}'$?

Answer (score 1):

If $a\geq 0,$ then
substitute $r-r'=\sqrt{a}v $ then you get $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{(r-r')^2 +a}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{(\sqrt{a}v)^2 +a}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{a}\sqrt{|v|^2 +1}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{a}\sqrt{|v|^2+ 2\cdot 0\cdot |v| +1}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{a}}\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} P_j (0) |v|^j=\frac{1}{\sqrt{a}}\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \frac{P_ (0)}{(\sqrt{a})^j} |r-r'|^j$$

Comment: But $\boldsymbol{r,r'}$ are vectors, so what is meant by $(\boldsymbol{r-r'})^2=(\boldsymbol{r-r'})\cdot(\boldsymbol{r-r'})$. Doesn't that give a problem in your expansion with uneven terms? Because $(\boldsymbol{r-r'})^j$ in the expansion would give a vector with uneven terms, and the potential is a scalar?

Comment: It is not a very big problem since $$(r-r' )^2 =|r-r'|^2 $$ and $|r-r'|$ means the lenght of vector $r-r'.$ So I correct the above expansion.